# Конвертация png в webp на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, png, webp

Как конвертировать с png в webp, пробовал с помощью библеотеки webptools и полез что то делать не разобравшись.Теперь чухаю голову и не знаю что делать, помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути, все правильно делал.

```
from webptools import cwebp

input_path = 'имя.png'
output_path = 'output.webp'

cwebp(input_path, output_path, "-q 80")  # -q 80 устанавливает качество изображения
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: А как сохранить это изображение в буфер io?